# Change style of component on click - react hook state

Tags: reactjs

I have a react code in which I have a parent file that imports question-box and answer-box.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import QuestionBox from "./QuestionBox";
import AnswerBox from "./AnswerBox";

const MainBox = () => {
  const [answer, toggleShowAnswer] = useState(<AnswerBox />);

  const faqAnswerHandler = function() {
    toggleShowAnswer((answer.style.visibility = "hidden"));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <QuestionBox />
      <AnswerBox />
    </div>
  );
};

export default FaqBox;
```

What I want to achieve is when I click on the QuestionBox component, then AnswerBox will disappear and vice-versa. I found some answers but they weren't useful. Help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

import QuestionBox from "./QuestionBox";
import AnswerBox from "./AnswerBox";

const MainBox = () => {
  const [answer, toggleShowAnswer] = useState(false);

  const faqAnswerHandler = function() {
    toggleShowAnswer(!answer);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <QuestionBox onClick={faqAnswerHandler} />
      {answer && <AnswerBox />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default FaqBox;
```

this will do what you want. rendering or not based on answer

but you can, of course manipulate CSS to hide it or not

Comment: Everything seems to be fine but the faqAnswerHandler function doesn't works.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-leakey-97si4?file=/src/App2.js maybe this is your problem... in "QuestionBox" should have a button element receiving the handler and calling it when clicked.